# Get parent and children when destructuring in javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have an object:

```
let param = {
    obj: {
        y: 1
    }
}
```

and we want to destructure it:

```
let { obj: {y} } = param
```

Now I have:

```
y //1
obj //not defined
```

The only way I found to use `obj` is:

```
let { obj, obj: {y} } = param
```

which I find too repetitive.

Is there any way to use `obj` without repeating it while destructuring?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do both, other than the way you find repetitive. You can, as I'm sure you know, just pull `obj` out and use `obj.y`...what's the use case here? Some more context might help

Comment: @DarrenSweeney There is no context at all, it's just basic knowledge since I'm using it quite often. And of course I know you can do `obj.y` but then destructuring might make no sense. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, **no**, not currently. The shortest syntax is what you have.

However, in the ECMAScript Proposals there is a draft called [As Patterns](https://github.com/zkat/proposal-as-patterns) in which the following would be possible. a.e.

```
let {obj: {y} as obj} = param;
```

Which, though admittedly not doing much length wise, is much clearer in use. It's at Stage 0 so it still has quite a way to go, but it does show that there is a need for something along the lines of what you're suggesting, but it simply hasn't been properly vetted through the channels and added to the spec as of yet.

This is somewhat understandable considering how new destructuring itself is. It's one of those features that JavaScript developers don't know they want until they run headlong into the question that you have today.